# Choose lightdm login screen location in multi monitor setup

Tags: lightdm

How can I set the location for the login screen with lightdm in a multi monitor setup.

If have two monitors (1920x1080) + (1920x1200) and currently after I boot the login is shown on the left (smaller) monitor. I would like to view it only on the right (bigger) monitor.

Switching the cables on the graphics card did not help, and I have already made the bigger screen my primary screen using xrandr:

```
xrandr --output DVI-1 --primary #big screen
```

After login my panel is on the primary screen but the login screen itself is shown on the other smaller screen. How can I configure lightdm to display the login only on the bigger screen.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Can't find the X11 configuration for LightDM

Answer (score 11):

At least with Ubuntu 16.04, which includes **lightdm-gtk-greeeter 2.0.1**, the following entry in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` can be used to fix the initial position of the login dialog on a certain monitor:

```
[greeter]
active-monitor=0
```

The `xrandr` workaround didn't work here, too.

Comment: It's probably important to note that the monitor number 0 is the left most monitor and not whichever is set to "primary". For example, on my triple monitor system where my center monitor is set to "primary" with XRandR, it seems I need to set `active-monitor` to `1`.

Comment: Interestingly `active-monitor` can be a semicolon separated list. Use the value `#cursor` to display the login dialog on the screen with cursor.

Comment: `#cursor` works indeed as expected. But I didn't see any difference using `0;1`; what's the list supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

This did the trick for me. Find out your primary screen:

```
$ xrandr
```

And create the file **/usr/bin/dualmon.sh** with the following command:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --primary
```

**Change DVI-0 for your primary screen.*

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dualmon.sh.
```

And add it to **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmon.sh
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmon.sh
```

Regards!

Comment: No need to create a script, simply write the command direct in to the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Once you find out your screen identifier as Ben suggested using `xrandr` then you can pick your desired display output (mine was called HDMI-1) and enter it direct in to the config file.

**/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf**

Search for the line "display-setup-script" and change it to read:

```
display-setup-script=xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary
```

Obviously replacing "HDMI-1" with your desired monitor, eg. "DVI-1" or "DP-1" for DVI or DisplayPort if not HDMI.

I currently use **lightdm-webkit2-greeter** so I don't have this option, but if you use the **lightdm-gtk-greeter** then you can do the following instead:

```
[greeter]
active-monitor=0
```

In the file **/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf**

Comment: Thanks, good to know I don't need to create a separate script file for this.