# Lightm gets stuck immediately after login, but slim and xdm seems to work in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, xorg, lightdm

Some background first. I was trying to reduce the power consumption in xubuntu in my laptop , which led me on a trail towards finding which GPU was being used for rendering the display. ( My laptop had ATI integrated graphics + NVIDIA dedicated graphics ). I must have done something on the way, which messed with Xorg or something. ( I tried prime-select, prime-switch and prime-offload ), all of which didn't seem to do much.

Reason for my suspicion

```
 $  nvidia-smi 
Wed Dec 22 13:07:08 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.102.04   Driver Version: 450.102.04   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8     2W /  N/A |      6MiB /  3911MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1017      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When i booted next time, the screen was stuck before the login in a black screen.
I was able to login via the tty. So i googled the issue and found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320691/ubuntu-boots-on-terminal-only-how-do-i-recover-the-gui-desktop), where there was a suggestion to remove xorg.conf was made. Removing the xorg.conf took me past that screen to the login screen, which I was able to pass, but now the GUI gets stuck immediately after login. ( I can see only the xfce panel, and the icons werent getting rendered ). A weird thing i noticed is, eventhough it was stuck, when i click the firefox button in the panel, the cursor switches to a loading cursor for sometime, and i could see firefox running through top.

I tried creating a new xorg.conf file using `X -configure` ( from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217758/how-to-make-an-xorg-conf-file) ), but the command kept saying the number of displays in the config doesnt match the displays available, while generating this config

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI3"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
        #Option     "ShadowPrimary"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DeleteUnusedDP12Displays"  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VariableRefresh"       # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Renaming this file as xorg.conf and placing it in /etc/X11/xorg.conf didnt help. Removing Xauthority and ~/.xinitrc also didnt help. So i tried to figure out what this config does, and noticed it is creating 2 displays unnecessarily even if i have only one. So i removed some parts, and made the amdgpu driver drive the only display i have. No improvement although, i now noticed the Xorg process disappeared from `nvidia-smi` output.

On the suggestion from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256946) and [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8581), i tried running startxfce4 after stopping lightdm, which now brought me to the GUI. But rebooting brought me square 1.

Tried making the `active_monitor=0` in the `greeter.conf` file. Didnt help. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234930/choose-lightdm-login-screen-location-in-multi-monitor-setup)

Then tried installing slim and xdm. The GUI starts working normally. But a few annoying issues crop up. logging in through slim, makes me enter the login password 3 times after login for wifi scanning and some other stuff, and the shutdown and reboot buttons are greyed out. In xdm, the password is asked once after some 10 minutes to unlock some keyring, before which firefox doesnt allow me to browse.

Figured out the slim password issue is due to the /sbin and /usr/sbin not being part of its PATH.

Realizing i am now relatively safe, I tried purging lightdm and lightdm-gtk-greeter, which i initially hesitated to do, since it insisted on removing `xubuntu-core`. Didnt help. Same issue happens.

I would like to get back my beloved lightdm back. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The has been so much done to the configuration and supporting files that getting a stock desktop back may be a bit of a challenge. Do you have any recent backups to restore from? 

Comment: No i dont have any backups. I have started to do that now after this debacle. This is my 3rd major crash. Guess 3rd time is the charm. I still have one bullet left to try i.e. to reinstall ubuntu-desktop. I am holding that back to see if there are any better ways.